# Show tiles from lower zoom levels if not available in current zoom level with ol-mapbox-style in openlayers

Tags: openlayers

I'm using openlayers with ol-mapbox-styles to show the imagery basemap layer from ArcGIS (see https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/basemap-styles/arcgis-imagery-style-get/). I'm aiming for a user experience, where there is always a basemap tile shown in my map. If the source doesn't provide a tile for the current zoom level, I'd like to show a tile from the highest available zoom level with the correct scaling. Is it possible to achieve this with the tools mentioned?

I already found a solution to show the basemap like this when zooming in:

```
layer.setMaxZoom(32);
layer.setMinResolution(0);
```

But this doesn't solve the problem if tiles are not available when panning at a high zoom level or zooming out.

Examples:

Initial low zoom:

[image: Inital low zoom]

Zoomed in:

[image: Zoomed in]

Panning in high zoom:

[image: Panning in high zoom]

Zooming out again:

[image: Zooming out again]

Comment: Try `layer.setPreload(Infinity)`

Comment: It works, thank you! Now I'll assess performance implications of this setting.